# Select part of word from query?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

In Access, I have a field like this:

> From the start until end at 01/05/2013, the XXXXXXX device was used.

I'm looking for a query that can extract the device name (in this case XXXXXXX). I was able to use mid() to get it somewhat working, but the sentence could be longer or shorter. What are some other ways to do this? Is there a find() I can use to find the location of "device"?

My SQL looks like:

```
SELECT Mid(Note, 68, 30)
FROM My_Log
WHERE Note LIKE "*, the*"
;
```

Comment: I do not do Access but I know that SUBSTR and INSTR functions are part of ANSI SQL. You can use these functions to cut that part of the word you need.

Comment: I am curious as to why you say you want an answer to pick out device, but accept an answer that picks out the word before device using a UDF, which would not be necessary for simply selecting a device? Perhaps you can rephrase your question to make your choice of answer clearer?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean "pick out" as in user input. I meant the SQL code would pick out the device name from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device name is the word before "device", and you want to find that word using only functions supported directly by the Access db engine, `Mid()`, `InStr()`, and `InstrRev()` can get the job done ... but it won't be pretty.

Here is an Immediate window session ...

```vb
Note = "From the start until end at 01/05/2013, the XXXXXXX device was used."
? Mid(Note, _
InstrRev(Note, " ", InStr(1, Note, " device") -1) +1, _
InStr(1, Note, " device") - InstrRev(Note, " ", InStr(1, Note, " device") -1) -1)
XXXXXXX
```

So you would then need to use that complex `Mid()` expression in a query.

However, if you can use a user-defined function in your query, the logic could be easier to manage.

```vb
Public Function FindDevice(ByVal pInput As String) As Variant
    Dim astrWords() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngUBound As Long
    Dim varReturn As Variant

    varReturn = Null
    astrWords = Split(pInput, " ")
    lngUBound = UBound(astrWords)
    For i = 0 To lngUBound
        If astrWords(i) = "device" Then
            varReturn = astrWords(i - 1)
        Exit For
    End If
    Next i
    FindDevice = varReturn
End Function
```

Then the query could be ...

```vb
SELECT FindDevice(Note) AS device_name
FROM My_Log
WHERE Note LIKE "*, the*"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the device, you can use Instr:

```
 ... WHERE Instr([Note], "Mydevice")>0
```

You can also use a table that lists devices:

```
SELECT Note FROM MyTable, ListTable
WHERE Note Like "*" & ListTable.Devices & "*"
```

Re comment:

```
SELECT Note
FROM MyTable
WHERE [Note] Like "*" & [enter device] & "*"
```

If you need to know where in notes you will find *device*

```
SELECT Note, InStr([Note],[enter device]) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comments this is Oracle query that may help you. Replace dual with with your table name and query should probably work. As I mentioned all functions I'm using in this query are ANSI SQL standard. The syntax you can fix yourself. You may run all queries separately to get start, end positions and lenght of your machine name, etc...:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(str, start_pos, end_pos) machine_name
  FROM
  (
   SELECT str, INSTR(str,'XXXXXXX') start_pos, Length('XXXXXXX') end_pos
     FROM
   (
   SELECT 'From the start until end at 01/05/2013, the XXXXXXX device was used.' str FROM dual
   )
 )
 /

SQL> 

MACHINE
-------
XXXXXXX
```

More generic approach with the same result - eliminating Length:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(str_starts, 1, end_pos) machine_name FROM -- Final string
(
 SELECT str_starts, INSTR(str_starts, ' ')-1 end_pos FROM -- end pos = last X pos in string starts - in 'XXXXXXX'
 (
  SELECT SUBSTR(str, start_pos) str_starts FROM    -- strig starts from first X
  (
   SELECT str, INSTR(str,'XXXXXXX') start_pos FROM  -- start_pos
   (
    SELECT 'From the start until end at 01/05/2013, the XXXXXXX device was used.' str FROM dual
   ))))
  /
```

Comment: In Access SQL: `SELECT Mid(str_starts, 1, end_pos) AS machine_name FROM 
(
 SELECT str_starts, INSTR(str_starts, ' ')-1 AS end_pos FROM  (
  SELECT Mid(str, start_pos) AS str_starts FROM   
  (
   SELECT str, INSTR(str,'XXXXXXX') AS start_pos FROM 
   (
    SELECT 'From the start until end at 01/05/2013, the XXXXXXX device was used.' AS str FROM dual
   ))))`

Comment: @HansUp, You should have added this to answers not comments. This is very nice example...

Comment: That's only the Access SQL version of your answer.  I hoped you might include it in your answer.

Comment: @HansUp, no I cannot do this, I guess no one but you can upgrade this to the answer as you should. It does not matter who writes first etc... We are trying to help others.