# Extracting part of a string using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, substring

I have a string which is of the form

```
Text I Want to Discard (TEXT I WANT)
```

I only want the part of the string contained in brackets. How do I go about getting this substring?

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: All answers are here - SUBSTR/INSTR functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483667/select-part-of-word-from-query/14484104#14484104

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
select substring(col, charindex('(', col), len(col))  
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06a9e/9)

Or check for both brackets. This gets the location of the opening bracket `(` and then returns the length of the string between the opening and closing bracket:

```
select substring(col, charindex('(', col), charindex(')', col) - charindex('(', col) +1)
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06a9e/14)

Comment: Don't forget to check for closing bracket - may be elsewhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below... it works...

```
DECLARE @c varchar(100)
SET     @c = 'Text I Want to Discard (TEXT I WANT)' 
SET @c = Replace(Replace(@c,')','_'),'(','_');
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    @c, 
    CHARINDEX('_', @c) + 1, 
    LEN(@c) - CHARINDEX('_', @c) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@c))
)
```

Comment: This only gives me the string without any brackets or spaces?