# Cut some data in column according on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Some kind of holyday/specialday calendar in process. I have a view (VSearchHoly) with three columns:

hday_name (just name), hday_date (dd.mm.yyyy), hday_year (1 or 0).

I need to create a procedure to find some days or names and cut off year in hday_date (to dd.mm) if hday_year in this row is 0.

Here is my search procedure, but I don't know how to cut a part of date depending on hday_year

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PHolySearch @holy_target VARCHAR(100)
AS
SELECT *
FROM VSearchHoly
WHERE hday_name LIKE ('%'+RTRIM(@holy_target)+'%')
OR hday_date LIKE ('%'+RTRIM(@holy_target)+'%')
```

Comment: "cut" - do you mean SUBSTRING?

Comment: Yes, substring dd.mm from full date. But only if "hday_year = 1" in current row.

Comment: Please google and learn about the SUBSTRING function in SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting part of a string using sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503909/extracting-part-of-a-string-using-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CASE, SUBSTRING and some form of CAST.  Something like this should work:

```
   SELECT   
      hday_name
      ,CASE WHEN hday_year in (0,1) THEN CAST((DAY(hday_date) AS CHAR(2)) +  CAST(YEAR(haday_date) as CHAR(2)) ELSE hday_date END as hday_date_modified
   FROM 
     VSearchHoly
   WHERE 
      hday_name LIKE ('%'+RTRIM(@holy_target)+'%')
      OR hday_date LIKE ('%'+RTRIM(@holy_target)+'%')
```